# postgresql loop fucntion to insert into table

Tags: postgresql, function, loops

I have a query that I run individually,

```
insert into table
select 
*
from query
where
sample = 1 --I change this value and run it again, range can be dynamic I run a different query to determine which values to use
```

I am terrible at loops(they just don't make sense to me), but was thinking it would be a better solution to write a function and do it all in one step, maybe even schedule it.

any ideas?

Comment: `where sample in (select ...)`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name , needs to happen in a certain order.

Comment: The order of insert is irrelevant, so how can the order be important?